# Own std::shared_ptr with std::make_shared

Tags: templates, c++11, shared-ptr

For a debug situation I need to implement an own version of the shared_ptr class. Typical when I use std::shared_ptr I use a typedef for convenience:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<myclass> myclassptr;
```

in a debug situation I want to extend the shared_ptr template, not the class myclass, with some additional debug methods instead of using the typedef:

```
class myclassptr : public std::shared_ptr<myclass>
{
  public:
   // some special tracking methodes
};
```

but that leave me with a cast at, which does not compile:

```
myclassptr mcp=std::make_shared<myclass>();
```

I already encapsulate the make_shared in a factory funktion like:

```
myclassptr createMyClass()
{
  return std::make_shared<myclass>();
}
```

but how can I get to my debug version?

Comment: Have a ctor that forwards to the base?

Comment: @Xeo Uaaa, that is what I forgot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `myclassptr` a constructor (and probably assignment operator too) which accepts a `std::shared_ptr`:

```
class myclassptr : public std::shared_ptr<myclass>
{
  public:
   // some special tracking methodes

    myclassptr(std::shared_ptr<myclass> arg)
      : std::shared_ptr<myclass>(std::move(arg))
    {}

    myclassptr& operator= (std::shared_ptr<myclass> src)
    {
      std::shared_ptr<myclass>::operator=(std::move(src));
      return *this;
    }
};
```

Depending on how you use `myclassptr`, you may or may not want to mark the constructor as `explicit`.

Comment: I had to add "*this->get()" and some "<myclass>" but I got it running with my VC C++ 2013. Thx

Comment: @MartinSchlott Sorry, the `get()` part shouldn't be there, that was a "typo" (bad identifier) in my code. It should be returning `myclassptr&` - I've updated the answer.